# Как отрендерить twig шаблон с include в node?

Tags: node.js, twig

Есть примерно такой шаблон

```
{% include 'template/header.html' %}
    <div class="content">
        ...
    </div>
{% include 'template/footer.html' %}
```

Мне надо отрендерить его в файл.

```
var Twig=require('twig');
var file='путь к файлу';
var html = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
html=Twig.twig(

  //Вариант 1
  {href:file}
  /*
  TwigException: Unsupported platform: Unable to do remote requests because there is no XMLHTTPRequest implementation
  */

  //Вариант 2
  {data:html}
  /*
  TwigException: Cannot extend an inline template.
  */

).render({
   ...
});
console.log(html);
fs.writeFile(dest, html, ... дальше все ок
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В гугле ничего не нарыл,тут мне не ответили..
Вобщем, сделал так:

```
{{ header }}
  <div class="content">
     ...
  </div>
{{ footer }}
```

render:

```
var Twig=require('twig');
var html = fs.readFileSync('путь к шаблону/report.twig', 'utf8');
var header = fs.readFileSync('путь/header.html'), 'utf8');
var footer = аналогично;
header=Twig.twig({data:header}).render({
  ... данные ...
});
footer= аналогично;

html=Twig.twig({data:html}).render({
  header:header,
  footer:footer,
  ... данные ...
});
console.log(html);
fs.writeFile('сгенерированное имя файла', html, ... дальше все ок
```

Всё работает.

Answer (score 3):

Я столкнулся с такой же задачей и решил вопрос следующим образом:

1) создаем index.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
    <h2>Hi {{ name }}!</h2>
    {% include 'body' %}
</body>
</html>
```

2) создаем body.twig

```
<p>We are glad to see you here</p>
```

3) создаем server.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var Twig = require('twig');

Twig.twig({
  id: 'body',
  data: fs.readFileSync('body.twig').toString()
});

var html = Twig.twig({
  id: 'index',
  ref: 'body',
  allowInlineIncludes: true,
  data: fs.readFileSync('index.twig').toString()
}).render({
  name: '@Darth'
});

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
  response.write(html);
  response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

4) запускаем node server.js (из командной строки) и перейдя по адресу http://localhost:8888/ мы увидим (если смотреть исходный код):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
    <h2>Hi @Darth!</h2>
    <p>We are glad to see you here</p></body>
</html>
```

P.S. основными моментами тут является то что всем шаблонам надо присваивать id и передавать в ref другого шаблона с включенной опцией `allowInlineIncludes: true`